# Check for equality of an URL with UIWebView's request or WKWebView's navigationAction.request

Tags: ios, swift, url, uiwebview

We'd like to load UIWebView (or WKWebView) content from a controlled list of URLs. We'd like to make sure there is no possible web navigation. We thought of `webView:shouldStartLoadWith:navigationType:` but the `request.url` from webView is appending a trailing slash to the URL's host, making it unfit for direct comparison.

Example of distinct URLs we'd like to load:

```
// example 1
let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/foo/")!

// example 2
let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/foo")!

// example 3
let url = URL(string: "https://example.com")!
```

How we load requests:

```
webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url))
```

How we control requests:

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    return request.url == url
}
```

First example works, because `request.url` is indeed equal to `https://example.com/foo/`.

Second example works, because `request.url` is indeed equal to `https://example.com/foo`.

But third example fails, because `request.url` is now `https://example.com/` instead of `https://example.com`

**To support proper comparison, how to normalize an URL the same way as UIWebView does?**

Comment: Try `webView.url` in `shouldStartLoadWith ` ?

Comment: @Jack `webView.url` doesn't exist: "_value of type 'UIWebView' has no member 'url'_"

Comment: FYI: `UIWebView` is deprecated. You should use [`WKWebView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview) instead

Comment: @MichaelHulet done, but same problematic, ah ah.

Answer (score 2):

One workaround is you can take the `absoluteString` property of URL and delete the last element if it is '/' and compare.

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    if let url = request.url{
        var requestUrlArray = url.absoluteString.map { String($0) }
        if let lastElement = requestUrlArray.last, lastElement == "/"{
            _ = requestUrlArray.popLast()
        }
        let requestUrlString =  requestUrlArray.joined()
        return requestUrlString == url.absoluteString
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it seems that you want to allow urls with the same host, in which case…

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    return request.url.host == url.host
}
```